# How to write txt file in s3 bucket with spark using write() method

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write `Dataset<string>` in `txt` format in s3 bucket using spark but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
```

[image]

My code:

```kotlin
override fun write(input: Dataset<String>) =

        input.coalesce(NUMBER_PARTITIONS).write().text(S3_BUCKET_PATH)
            .also {
                LOGGER.logInfo(
                    LOG_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE,
                    READ_DATA_METHOD,
                    WRITE_MESSAGE
                )
            }
```

[image]

My spark configuration:

```scala
object SparkConfiguration {
    private const val SPARK_MASTER_NAME = "spark.master"
    private const val SPARK_APP_NAME_CONFIG = "spark.app.name"
    fun buildSparkSession(config: Config): SparkSession {
        return SparkSession.builder()
            .config(buildSparkConfig(config))
            .orCreate
    }
    fun buildSparkConfig(config: Config): SparkConf = SparkConf()
        .setMaster(config.getString(SPARK_MASTER_NAME))
        .setAppName(config.getString(SPARK_APP_NAME_CONFIG))
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Comment: thank you by tip !
I will do this!!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to having no permissions when running your Spark Job:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified by setting the fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively).
```

Make sure that you have permissions to run your code against S3.

Ideally set your credentials in the conf/core-site.xml as:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>XXXXXX</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>XXXXXX</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

or reinstall awscli on your machine and .

```
pip install awscli
```

then

```
aws configure
```

Comment: I try this but still now work

ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>123</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>3SGBA8DYF9SVCFB0</RequestId><HostId>4rSyL0w+h9VdAJhjkceUibs01LL8kYzYcsLog0g6Jvlmw7N4kQUSsAzf6uP/PM3vOyjLiXipZ68=</HostId></Error>

Comment: What did you set as your access keys?